# Javascript. Does it exists depth limit when object has reference to itself ? How does interpreter optimizes this case?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I understand correctly, in code below exists recursive reference:

```
var object = {}
object.nested = object;
console.log(object)
```

In console I can see infinite reference. So, how does interpreter optimizes this case ? How does this reference works ? Does it cause the memory leaks ? Does it exists depth limit ?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QbR3o8cGnXU924nNs0cE

Comment: Optimise...how? What you have is simply an object. I doubt it's going to get more optimised than that. If you delete the reference to it, it should be garbage collected, as GCs should understand circular references.

Comment: It's just a reference; there's no "depth". The console is just some code doing something inappropriate with the object.

Comment: thanks for ur comments! I got it!