# Why does `window.window.window` work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It doesn't matter if you write `window` or `window.window` or `window.window.window`, it still works.

I wanted to know what is the logic behind this.

I also checked it will work for **`window * 144`** and after 145 it won't.
Is this intended in the language?

Comment: `window` is global, `window.window` is self referencing. But it's interesting that this does not work infinitely, I didn't know that :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35788475/476

Comment: Why is this question getting this many upvotes? It's not that great...

Comment: Somewhatish related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40452539/476

Comment: I can't reproduce that limit at least not around 144.

Comment: @Cerbrus Javascript Wats often accumulate upvotes like crazy… ;)

Comment: There is no limit. May be you are getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

Comment: I guess my question is not clear. And trust me I wrote this question after checking all of this even the specification. But im asking if its self reference then why it wont work for 145 times?

Comment: Define better how exactly it fails "to work".

Comment: The _"Maximum call stack size exceeded"_  error sounds like an error in the interpreter that does have to keep track of each reference.

Comment: Because 144 is 42 * 3 + ((4 + 2) * 3).  We know that 42 is life and you get 3 lives on old school games, like Javascript. Simples.

Comment: @Archer [ಠ_ಠ](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C-QnI3AXYAAsJqG.jpg:large)